# Некорректный формат получаемой картинки. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения

```
import requests

url = "https://ronreiter-meme-generator.p.rapidapi.com/meme"

querystring = {"font":"Impact","font_size":"10","meme":"Condescending-Wonka","top":"Some text","bottom":"some text"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "ApiHost",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "myApiKey",

    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

text = response.text
img_file = open('C:/python/test/img/image.jpg', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
img_file.write(text)
img_file.close()
```

Возможно вопрос дикий, но все же. Мне нужно получить некую картинку по параметрам с сайта. И сайт мне ее дает, но как ее записать? Я не силен в этом и если в коде выше написал бред, прошу прощения! Файл создается без ошибок, но не открывается. Программы говорят недопустимый формат. Как правильно ее обработать?

Comment: `open(..., "wb"); write(response.content)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вся проблема в том, что метод `.text` возвращает `bytes`, а вы его записываете как `str`

Это должно всё исправить. Запись в файл в Python по умолчанию `utf-8`

```
with open('C:/python/test/img/image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html